# Click on Anchor Tag in Modal box send href link to AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Respected Community,

I'm working on a task which requires that when a user clicks on upload button of a Dropzone box, a Modal Box must appear asking the user where to save the uploading files on localhost. The Modal Box shows a list of already existing directories in a certain drive and provides an option to create a new Folder if desired. Clicking on Create a new Folder button from Modal Box 1 opens up another Modal Box which asks the user to input Foldername which is sent through AJAX to a php page that creates user defined folder in the directory.

The problem I'm facing is that, upon clicking the foldername from already existing folders list in Modal Box 1, the selected foldername must be sent through AJAX to another php page from where the dropzone can know where to upload the files. Any help will be highly regarded.

Thanks...

**Here is my code that takes foldername from the user and creates a Folder in a directory:**

```
$foldername = $_REQUEST['foldername'];
$structure = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $foldername;
if(!file_exists($structure)){
  if(mkdir($structure, 0777, true)) {
    die('Success');
  }else {
    die("Folder `{$structure}` failed to be created");
  }
}
```

**Here's the code to upload dropzone files in user defined folder (which is not currently working):**

```
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$storeFolder = 'uploads/'; // "$_POST['variable']" is the folder where files will be uploaded  
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds . $storeFolder . $ds;         
    $targetFile =  $targetPath . $_FILES['file']['name'];     
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);         
}
```

**Here is the JavaScript code that I'm using to perform tasks:**

```
$( function() {
var dialog, dialogMain, form;
var name = $("input[name=name]");
var path = $("input[name=path]");
var allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( path );

function addFolder() {
  var valid = true;
  allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
  if (valid) {
    $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
      "<td>" + "<a href='#'>" + name.val() + "</a>" + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + path.val() + "</td>" +
    "</tr>" );
    dialog.dialog( "close" );
  }
  return valid;
}

dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( {
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 350,
  width: 350,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "Create a Folder" : {
        text: "Create a Folder",
        id: "indlg",
        click: addFolder 
    },
    Cancel: function() {
      dialog.dialog( "close" );
    }
  },
  close: function() {
    form[ 0 ].reset();
    allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
  }
});

dialogMain = $( "#main-dialog" ).dialog( {
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 300,
  width: 390,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    Cancel: function() {
        dialogMain.dialog( "close" );
    }
  }
});

form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  addFolder();
});

$( "#createFolder" ).button().on( "click", function() {
  dialog.dialog( "open" );
});

$( "#upload" ).button().on( "click", function() {
  dialogMain.dialog( "open" );
});

$('#indlg').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'create.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { foldername : name.val() },
      success: function(output) {
        alert(output);
      }
    });
});
```

} );

Comment: What are you tried can you share demo link?

Comment: You should either be able to add the inputs for the chosen folder or custom/new folder directly to your dropzone form, or if that is no option and you really need the modals you could serialze your dropzone form ( `$(dropzoneForm).serializeArray()` ) then push your folder value into that array (`.push({folder: "myNewFolder"})`) in your modal and turn it back into a urlEncoded form with `$.param(completeFormData)` before sending it via ajax or post.

Comment: @vadivel I'm doing this on a localhost... All my work in on my machine, so can't share link... Sorry, you have to do with the code I have shared :/

Comment: That's exactly what I want @Lapskaus. I want to add inputs for the chosen folder name or custom/new folder to my dropzone. So that selected files can be uploaded directly to the selected folder.

Comment: @Taimoor Mughal ok thanks how to try in my side?

Comment: Well if you don't need the modals/dialogs, just put the input fields in the form that contains your dropzone. The values then get send to your php endpoint on submit and you can validate and either select or create the folder there.

Comment: _@vadivel a_ Sorry, I didn't get your point. Are you asking that how you can try the code on your machine? 